# Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again. -Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, authentication

I make a simple login asp net web application in Visual Studio 2015. I successfully publish it into local ip and public ip. Then I update some pages in my web application so I run it first in browser(local) to try but it said "Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again." when try to login. Definitely I input right password.

Before this I also face same problem and solved it by delete C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS" folder. But now I try it but cannot solve.

I suspect it appoint to wrong login database which is C:\Users\bcd\Documents\My Web Sites\loginTest\loginTest\App_Data, it should appoint to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\loginTest\App_Data.

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
   <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" ></customErrors>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: please show us your connection string which you add in webconfig

Comment: I don't put connection string in my webconfig as shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy App_Data folder from

```
C:\Users\bcd\Documents\My Web Sites\loginTest\loginTest\App_Data
```

and paste it into `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\loginTest\App_Data`to replace the folder.